# How can I use js eval to return a value?

Tags: javascript

I need to evaluate a custom function passed from the server as a string. It's all part of a complicated json I get, but anyway, I seem to be needing something along the lines:

```
var customJSfromServer = "return 2+2+2;"
var evalValue = eval(customJSfromServer);
alert(evalValue) ;// should be "6";
```

Obviously this is not working as I expected. Any way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The first method is to delete **return** keywords and the semicolon:

```
var expression = '2+2+2';
var result = eval('(' + expression + ')')
alert(result);
```

note the **'('** and **')'** is a must.

or you can make it a function:

```
var expression = 'return 2+2+2;'
var result = eval('(function() {' + expression + '}())');
alert(result);
```

even simpler, do not use eval:

```
var expression = 'return 2+2+2;';
var result = new Function(expression)();
alert(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In your second example, the `eval('(function() {' + expression + '}())');` fails in case there is a comment on the last line of the expression, with an error like **unexpected end of input**. To fix it, add a newline to the end: `'\n}())'`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ,i used second example ,with a new line '\n}())' at the end  and it worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

If you can guarantee the `return` statement will always exist, you might find the following more appropriate:

```
var customJSfromServer = "return 2+2+2;"
var asFunc = new Function(customJSfromServer);
alert(asFunc()) ;// should be "6";
```

Of course, you could also do:

```
var customJSfromServer = "return 2+2+2;"
var evalValue = (new Function(customJSfromServer)());
alert(evalValue) ;// should be "6";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var customJSfromServer = "2+2+2;"
var evalValue = eval(customJSfromServer);
alert(evalValue) ;// should be "6";
```

Answer (score 2):

There should not be return statement , as eval will read this as statment and will not return value.

```
var customJSfromServer = "2+2+2;"
var evalValue = eval( customJSfromServer );
alert(evalValue) ;// should be "6";
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: That probably also works if you declare `evalValue` outside of the string.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
function answer() {
    return 42;
}

var a = eval('answer()');
console.log(a);
```

You need to wrap the return inside a function and it should pass the value on from the eval.

Answer (score 1):

Modify server response to get "2+2+2" (remove "return") and try this:

```
var myvar = eval(response);
alert(myvar);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `anonymous function`

```js
let str = 'return 2+2+2'
let res = new Function(str)()
console.log(res) // 6

let fn = new Function('e','return e+e+e')
    res = fn(3)
console.log(res) // 9
```

Answer (score -2):

In 2019 using Template Literals:

```
var customJSfromServer = "2+2+2;"
var evalValue = eval(`${customJSfromServer}`);
alert(evalValue) ;// should be "6";
```