# Why is this JavaScript eval failing?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have some code which just does not do what is supposed to do. After inserting a lot of `console.log`, it finally all boiled down to an eval that made a variable undefined.

The relevant segment of code is:

```
console.log(str);
console.log(typeof str);
console.log(str.length);
var ret = eval(str);
console.log(ret);
```

and the output from Firebug-console is

```
[[["index.php?page=Int_JobModule&methode=Page_EditJob&ro=1&id=20121218baasbw03","20121218baasbw03","dauervorgang plumperquatsch4711x"]]]
string
135
undefined
```

So, clearly, `eval` has done this - but I can't figure out what's wrong there.

Comment: `eval` is evil! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea for more info

Comment: Have you tried to `JSON.parse()` that?

Comment: Yes do use JSON.parse. But if for some wild reason you can't - even your eval should work: http://jsfiddle.net/YuEWH/

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2EXta/ (P.S. `str.len` should be `str.length`)

Comment: what are you trying to do specifically? There's probably a better way that doesn't use `eval`

Comment: Your code works for me. I dont know why your are getting that undefined

Comment: Is this literally your code? Are you sure that the `console.log` statements are lexically immediately before the `eval` and are not part of a separate function?

Comment: In Chrome you get an object with the array on the top and an unidentified response in console. Maybe it's what is misleading you.

Comment: This cannot be the code you actually used, because `str.len` has to be `str.length`.

Comment: Thanks for all comments :)
Yes, this is not the code that is actually running, because the dev-machine is not online. I had to type everything, no copy&paste. Which explains the .len/.length-mixup - I have fixed it now.However, the statements are running in exactly that sequence within the same function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399024/how-can-i-use-js-eval-to-return-a-value

Comment: Thanks @Rocket Hazmat - I have no execuse for not using JSON.parse here, it works now. If you'd re-post your comment, I'll accept is as answer :)