# Is there a way to evaluate a function defined as a string by using eval()?

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I would like to store a function definition in a string, like for example:

```
var funcString = 'function(){ return 4+4 }'
```

Can I use eval() to evaluate the function?

Like for example:

```
var result = eval(funcString)
```

which will evaluate the string in funcString as a function and return 4+4 (8) in result.

edit: So from what you've told me I understood that I shouldn't use eval in that way, but for my case I don't think there is another way.

I would like to define a set of rules in a separate file and I want to instruct my Javascript Library to look into this file and search for the rules. The following is an example of a rule:

```
rule('logOut', (function() { return !JSLibrary.compareUserDetails })(), (function() { console.log("\n\nError: logged out user did not match\n\n\n") })())
```

I would like to evaluate both of the functions defined in the rules and I think that eval is the only way to do it. I don't know if there exist any other.

Comment: Think very, very carefully about *why* you want to do this, as it is a terrible idea by just about every conceivable metric. Also, `let eight = new Function('return 4 + 4;')();`. Also terrible.

Comment: The function is added to the top-level scope, and you didn't give it a name.

Comment: Don't use eval for anything ever it's a horrible practice. Sure there might be a few rare scenarios it is deemed acceptable but I don't think they apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use js eval to return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399024/how-can-i-use-js-eval-to-return-a-value)

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry that I didn't notice it before. I'll edit my question to provide what I'm really looking for.

Comment: @Nope, question is now edited it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fair warning, [`eval` is "evil."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198031/2329281) I'll answer your question regardless, but you might want to rethink using `eval`.

In JavaScript, functions are values, just like `5`, `'Stack Overflow'` and `document`. In fact, what `function myFunction(args) { body }` does is create a function and throw it into a variable called `myFunction`*.

Say you wanted to take that function and put it into another variable. You can just say `var otherVariable = myFunction`. And if you want to call that function, you can just say `otherVariable()`.

But say you want a function that isn't bound to a name, for instance if you're passing it to another function. You can use an anonymous function, defined as `function(args) { body }`. That's what's inside the string you're `eval`-ing. Anonymous functions are just like any other function, and you can call them as such. Actually, you can even call them right out of the result of `eval` by tacking on some parentheses at the end.

Unfortunately, it's not that easy though. You can't just write a line of code with an anonymous function definition and expect it to run: you will instead get an error complaining about it not being named. To fix this, throw some parenthesis around the definition to force it to be an expression instead of a statement.

Your final working code will look like this:

```
var funcString = '(function(){ return 4+4 })'
var result = eval(funcString)()
```

Sure, you should never use `eval` for this particular use, but I hope you learned a bit about JavaScript from this answer anyways.

* There's more to it than that, such as hoisting, but that doesn't really matter in this explanation.

Comment: Did you test this?  `var funcString = 'function(){ return 4+4 }'` won't compile in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use of an [immediately invoked function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) can call a function with eval.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = eval('(function(){return 4+4;})()');
```

WARNING: do not ever do this: it's insecure, a performance-killer, harder to read/understand, etc

Comment: While correct, this answer could be improved by warnings to not ever do this: it's insecure, a performance-killer, harder to read/understand, etc.